# dockerのコンテナに変更されていない問題について

Tags: docker

dockerにCentOSのイメージを立てて
その中で,rails,mysql等をインストールしています(dockerfileでrailsやmysqlを設定しているわけではありません。あくまでvmwareみたいな使い方をしています。)

そのさい

> ruby -v
>   ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

となっていたものが

docker抜けて(ctrl+p ctrl+q)をして
もう一度dockerを立ち上げ(docker restart)
先ほどの

> ruby -v
>   bash: ruby: command not found

となります。なぜ変更が反映されないのでしょうか？ご教示お願いいたします。

(fileとかが消えているということはありません)

Comment: Dockerは中身が保存されるわけではないん為一度終了すると中でまたインストールし直さないと行けなくなります

Answer (score 0):

> dockerfileでrailsやmysqlを設定しているわけではありません。あくまでvmwareみたいな使い方をしています。

まさにコレが原因です。
Dockerコンテナは一度再起動すると変更内容が揮発してしまいますので、Dockerfileでやるのが良いと思います。